# In which situations would Stdin::lock be useful?

Tags: rust, stdin

[`Stdin::lock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.lock):

```rust
pub fn lock(&self) -> StdinLock<'_>
```

In which situations would this be useful?

Comment: you've linked directly to the documentation, is there something there that is unclear?

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation states](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html), emphasis mine:

> A handle to the standard input stream of a process.
>
> Each handle is a shared reference to a global buffer of input data to this process. **A handle can be `lock`'d to gain full access to [`BufRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html) methods (e.g., `.lines()`)**. Reads to this handle are otherwise locked with respect to other reads.

```rust
use std::io::{self, prelude::*};

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    
    dbg!(stdin.lines().count()); // fails!
    
    let stdin = stdin.lock();
    dbg!(stdin.lines().count());
}
```

```
error[E0599]: no method named `lines` found for struct `std::io::Stdin` in the current scope
   --> src/main.rs:6:16
    |
6   |       dbg!(stdin.lines().count());
    |                  ^^^^^ method not found in `std::io::Stdin`
    |
    = note: the method `lines` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `std::io::Stdin: std::io::BufRead`
            which is required by `&mut std::io::Stdin: std::io::BufRead`
```

Comment: Can you give another example except the one [stated](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#method.lock) in the documentation?

Comment: @109149 can you explain why the example in the documentation is insufficient?

Comment: I don't understand what is the difference between using the `stdin::lock` and [not using it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Stdin.html#examples).

Comment: In a single-threaded program, there is no difference. In a multi-thread program, if you don't use `lock` another thread could intercept some of the lines.